# jQuery select parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, parent-child, parent

This might be a duplicate question, however I **did** search and I got so many different answers that I don't know which to use or how to do this.

```
<?
if(isset($content))
{
    $i = 1;
    foreach($content as $item)
    {
        echo "<li><a href='#' name='" . $item['id'] . "'>" . $item['title'] . "</a></li>";
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

I've added a function to these links with jQuery to handle an ajax call. I select the links as follows:

```
    $("#tips_list ul li a").click(function(e)   { //... }
```

However, this doesn't make a lot of sense because now you have to click on the actual text instead of the list item. So I figured I'd re-structure my HTML so the anchor tag wraps around the `li` tag.

```
    `<a href="#" name=""><li>foo</li></a>`
```

I then changed my jQuery code accordingly:

```
    $("#tips_list ul a li").click(function(e)   { //... }
```

However, now, when I click.. it grabs the list item tag as `$(this)`; which means I can't really grab the name attribute from the anchor tag. So! What I need to do is to grab the `name` attribute from the **parent** anchor tag. And I honestly have no clue what the easiest way to do this is. I'm not that experienced with jQuery.

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: [$(this).parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) doesn't work? You should also consider updating your css to handle your LI's better.

Comment: Don't put an `a` around a `li`, it is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about going back to the original method, and set `#tips_list ul li a {display:block}` in your CSS? That should make the a expand and take up the whole li, making the whole li seem clickable. Your original code should then work fine.

Comment: Okay, apparently I was making this too hard on myself and there was a much easier non-jQ way. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Keep the old markup.  The later one is quite cranky and use the following script.

```
$("#tips_list ul li").click(function(e)   {
    var name = $(this).children("a").attr("name");
    alert(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent of an element you just need to use
`$(this).parent()`
So I would do this:
`$(this).parent('a').attr('name');`